# How to view a received packet

Tags: python

i am connecting to a tor node, sending a packet, what i am wondering is how do i view the packet that is received ?

this is how i am currently sending the the packet :

```
import ssl
import socket
import struct
import binascii

s = socket.socket()
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
ssl_sock.connect(("", 443))

pkt = struct.pack(">HBHH", 0, 7, 2, 3)
ssl_sock.send(pkt)
```

Thanks

Comment: And all the SO users DDOS your server now because you left the ip in.

Comment: As for viewing the packet, do you want to just view a hex dump?

Comment: Yep basically, what is the most effective way to view it, just want to try and understand the repsonce :)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work:

```
recv_pkt = ssl_sock.recv(1500)
print ":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in recv_pkt)
```

I just put 1500 for the buffer size.  I really don't know what you are doing.  The print is just a quick way to print a hex string.